# object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, computer-science

Code:

```py
def web_content_div(web_content,class_path):
  web_content_div= web_content.find_all('div',{'class': class_path})
  try:
    spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
    texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
  except IndexError:
    texts=[]
  return texts


def real_time_price(stock_code):
  url= 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code + '&.tsrc=fin-srch'
  try:
     r=requests.get(url)
     web_content = bs4(r.text,'lxml')
     texts = web_content_div(web_content,'My (6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt (6px) W(100%)')
     if texts != []:
        price,change=texts[0],texts[1]
     else:
         price,change=[],[]
  except ConnectionError:
    price,change=[],[]
  return price,change
Stock = ['BRK-B']
print(real_time_price('BRK-B'))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9b2ae2d7ddc6> in <cell line: 25>()
     23   return price,change
     24 Stock = ['BRK-B']
---> 25 print(real_time_price('BRK-B'))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2306     def __getattr__(self, key):
   2307         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2308         raise AttributeError(
   2309             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2310         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

wanted to resolve the find error. Tried changing find_all to find but it gives same error

Comment: Well, *did* you mean to call `find()`?